# What's the connection between the User Profile Service and the People And Groups hidden list? SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, migration, user-information-list

I'm looking to understand the connection between the User Profile Service and the hidden User Information List.

Here's what I'm experiencing.

New SharePoint 2013 farm with a migrated UPS from a SharePoint 2010 environment. The UPS is functioning properly. When I create a new site collection, I expect that the hidden list to be empty except for the first few accounts that touch it. However I've got every group and user from my AD environment in there.

I thought I understood the hidden list to only retain people who have accessed the site. How did the entire AD get in there?